# Computing an integral along a curve

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = z - \frac{1}{z}$. Let $\gamma $ be the straight line from $1$ to $i$. Find $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz $

**Attempt:**

Let $\gamma(t) = (1-t,t)$. We know if $F(z) = \frac{z^2}{2} - \log z $, then $F'(z) = f(z)$. So

$$ \int_{\gamma} f dz = F( \gamma(1) ) - F( \gamma(0) ) = \frac{i^2}{2} - \log i - \frac{1}{2} + \log 1 = - \frac{1}{4} - \log i$$

Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct if the function is analytical so that the integral does not depend on the exact path. But you are not using the parameterization of the $\gamma$ curve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $z=1-t+it=1+(i-1)t$, we have

$$\int_{t=0}^1\left(1+(i-1)t-\frac1{1+(i-1)t}\right)\,d(1+(i-1)t)=\\
(i-1)\int_{t=0}^1\left(1+(i-1)t-\frac1{1+(i-1)t}\right)\,dt=\\
(i-1)\left.\left(t+(i-1)\frac{t^2}2-\frac1{i-1}\ln(t+\frac1{i-1})\right)\right|_0^1$$